# Consolidate many queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm looking to achieve my goals as described below using one single query, as opposed to multiple queries as I currently have to use.

The problem I am having is that data from the `wp_usermeta` table is stored as a `meta_key`/`meta_value` in 2x columns, as opposed to each type of data having it's own column. While the reasoning for this makes sense, it does mean I'm stumped at this point.

The database in question is for a WordPerss site, should anyone wish to replicate this.

## My goals

For each user who has at least one image/video post I need to grab the following details -

```
+-----------------------+---------------+------------------------------------------------+
| Description           | Table         | Column                                         |
+-----------------------+---------------+------------------------------------------------+
| User ID               | `wp_users`    | `ID`                                           |
| Display Name          | `wp_users`    | `display_name`                                 |
| First Name            | `wp_usermeta` | `meta_value` (WHERE `meta_key` = 'first_name'  |
| Description           | `wp_usermeta` | `meta_value` (WHERE `meta_key` = 'description' |
| Facebook profile link | `wp_usermeta` | `meta_value` (WHERE `meta_key` = 'facebook'    |
| Google+ profile link  | `wp_usermeta` | `meta_value` (WHERE `meta_key` = 'google_plus' |
| Twitter profile link  | `wp_usermeta` | `meta_value` (WHERE `meta_key` = 'twitter'     |
+-----------------------+---------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

## My current solution

First I select the ID and display name of all users who have at least 1 image/video post (this is one single query) -

```
SELECT DISTINCT `wp_users`.`ID`, `wp_users`.`display_name`
FROM `wp_posts`
INNER JOIN `wp_users`
WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_type` = "attachment"
AND `wp_posts`.`post_status` = "inherit"
AND `wp_posts`.`post_author` = `wp_users`.`ID`
AND (
    `wp_posts`.`post_mime_type` LIKE "image%"
    OR `wp_posts`.`post_mime_type` LIKE "video%"
)
```

Next, I have to loop through each result from the first query and select the first name, description and social media links for each (this is one example, for `user_id = 2`) -

```
SELECT `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key`, `wp_usermeta`.`meta_value`
FROM `wp_usermeta`
WHERE `wp_usermeta`.`user_id` = 2
AND (
    `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'first_name'
    OR `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'description'
    OR `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'facebook'
    OR `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'google_plus'
    OR `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'twitter'
);
```

As part of the loop where the second query is run I also have to insert those results into the results from the first. All of this not only means extra code, but leads to a longer execution time.

My full code can be found here - http://pastebin.com/P2jv3WTt

Is this goal achievable with MySQL, or is it simply not something it is able to do? Thanks.

## What I've tried

I have tried to join to the `wp_usermeta` table as follows, outputting the results as a named column, but there is an issue - the only results are for users who have an entry for every single `meta_key` in the `wp_usermeta` table, but some don't (no Twitter profile link, for example).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    u.`ID`,
    u.`display_name`,
    m1.`meta_value` AS first_name,
    m2.`meta_value` AS description,
    m3.`meta_value` AS facebook,
    m4.`meta_value` AS google_plus,
    m5.`meta_value` AS twitter
FROM `wp_users` u
JOIN `wp_posts` p
JOIN `wp_usermeta` m1 ON (m1.user_id = u.id AND m1.meta_key = 'first_name')
JOIN `wp_usermeta` m2 ON (m2.user_id = u.id AND m2.meta_key = 'description')
JOIN `wp_usermeta` m3 ON (m3.user_id = u.id AND m3.meta_key = 'facebook')
JOIN `wp_usermeta` m4 ON (m4.user_id = u.id AND m4.meta_key = 'google_plus')
JOIN `wp_usermeta` m5 ON (m5.user_id = u.id AND m5.meta_key = 'twitter')
WHERE p.`post_type` = "attachment"
AND p.`post_status` = "inherit"
AND p.`post_author` = u.`ID`
AND (
    p.`post_mime_type` LIKE "image%"
    OR p.`post_mime_type` LIKE "video%"
)
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Stick the first query into the second one using IN() operator? Both queries look pretty inefficient, but where you have `WHERE wp_usermeta.user_id = 2` - replace that with `WHERE wp_usermeta.user_id IN(first_query_here);`

Comment: can you join users to the meta table on wp_users.id = wp_usermeta.user_id and then put all of the relevant information into the first select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most straightforward solution would be like this. Simply do a join for each meta-value you need.

By using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` to join the meta-data, you will still keep users for which some of these meta-data don't exist.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.ID, u.DisplayName,
       fn.meta_value AS firstname, fb.meta_value AS facebook, (etc.)
FROM wp_Users u
INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON p.post_author = u.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_usermeta fn ON fn.UserId = u.ID AND fn.meta_key = 'first_name'
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_usermeta fb ON fb.UserId = u.ID AND fb.meta_key = 'facebook'
--- (etc. for each meta column you need to join)
WHERE p.post_type = 'attachment'
AND p.post_status = 'inherit'
AND (p.post_mime_type LIKE 'image%'
    OR p.post_mime_type LIKE 'video%')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried this, and it's almost there. The only problem is that if there is not an entry for every `meta_key` in the `wp_usermeta` table for a user, no results are returned for that user.

Comment: Okay. That problem is fixed by changing the inner joins to left outer joins. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `wp_users`.`ID`,
    `wp_users`.`display_name`,
    `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key`,
    `wp_usermeta`.`meta_value`
FROM
    `wp_posts`
        INNER JOIN
    `wp_users` ON (`wp_posts`.`post_author` = `wp_users`.`ID`)
        LEFT JOIN
    `wp_usermeta` ON (`wp_usermeta`.`user_id` = `wp_users`.`ID`)
WHERE
    `wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'attachment'
        AND `wp_posts`.`post_status` = 'inherit'
        AND (`wp_posts`.`post_mime_type` LIKE 'image%'
        OR `wp_posts`.`post_mime_type` LIKE 'video%')
        AND `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` 
            IN ('first_name', 'description', 'facebook', 'google_plus', 'twitter');
```

LEFT JOIN must return you posts and users even if there are no meta associated with users.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While the query does return all of the data I require, it does so in a way that is unfortunately no good to me. Rather than one row per user, each user has 1 row per `meta_key`/`meta_value` pair (so up to 5 rows per user).

Comment: Use LEFT join instead of INNER, or LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN.

Comment: But keep in mind that it is faster to perform one join instead of five.

Comment: I realise that, but unfortunately the results for each user are no good to me if they are all on a separate rows. Also, I've used `LEFT JOIN` as in your answer and for both joins, but the results are the same in both cases. Thanks.

Comment: I meant use LEFT JOIN in the query you posted in your question to join meta tables.

Comment: Oh I see... Yes, that does the job. It returns it as `NULL`, but that's fine, I can account for that in my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT meta.user_id, meta.meta_key, meta.meta_value 
FROM wp_usermeta meta JOIN wp_posts posts
ON posts.post_author = meta.user_id
WHERE posts.post_type = "attachment"
AND posts.post_status = "inherit"
AND posts.post_mime_type RLIKE "^(image|video)"
AND meta_key IN ('first_name', 'description','facebook','google_plus','twitter');
```

Keep in mind that wp_posts.post_author and wp_usermeta.user_id should be indexes, otherwise this query will be slow.

Better yet if you have a joined index on wp_usermeta: `user_key (user_id, meta_key)`. You can add this with the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta ADD KEY user_key(user_id, meta_key);
```

PS If you also need display_name from the wp_users table, then you have to join it too:

```
SELECT meta.user_id, users.display_name, meta.meta_key, meta.meta_value 
FROM wp_usermeta meta JOIN wp_posts posts
ON posts.post_author = meta.user_id
JOIN wp_users users 
ON users.id = meta.user_id
WHERE posts.post_type = "attachment"
AND posts.post_status = "inherit"
AND posts.post_mime_type RLIKE "^(image|video)"
AND meta_key IN ('first_name', 'description','facebook','google_plus','twitter');
```